# Are sql window aggregate functions calculated only once

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'll demonstrate with example: Consider a table with columns 
id(PK),category,value,total_category_value

I want to calculate total_category_value as the total of all [value] who have the same category. I know well that this can be done by `sum(value) over (pertition by category)`. Let's say there are 100 rows with category A, then the sum aggregation of these 100 will be stored in each of the 100 rows at the field total_category_value. Will this calculation be performed once, or 100 times?

If the answer is 100 times: will it the be better to create a temp table by group-by-category'ing the original, calculate sum there, and then update with inner join?

Comment: Check the execution plans

Comment: I'm using sql server. Not sure if I can deduce the answer to my question from seeing the exec plan, but I will try and if not, then maybe post it here.

Comment: Why does it matter *how* it is calculated - surely the only question to ask yourself at the outset is - if it *good enough* for your purposes?

Comment: Half of sql questions I've seen everywhere are about performance. Recently, by choosing another route for one of my queries( vartable vs cte) I changed time takes from 1 minute to <1 second. These things matter, and while many things rely on execution plans that need testing, I thought this question might have an absolute answer.